# Is it necessary to add try do ...catch for every 'handle_call' function?

Tags: elixir

In `erlang`, if there is no try catch, error in `handle_call` function will crash the GenServer.
When it is crashed, it is not easy to find where is the problem because a lot of crash and restart log.

My question is why so many handle_call haven't `try catch` statement? What's the consideration?

The following code is from [Nx](https://github.com/elixir-nx/nx) project `stream.ex` file for studying only.

```
  @impl true
  def handle_call(:recv, from, {output, waiting, acc, fun}) do
    case :queue.out(output) do
      {:empty, output} ->
        {:noreply, {output, :queue.in(from, waiting), acc, fun}}

      {{:value, data}, output} ->
        {:reply, {:ok, data}, {output, waiting, acc, fun}}
    end
  end

  @impl true
  def handle_call(:done, _from, {output, waiting, acc, fun}) do
    if :queue.is_empty(output) do
      for from <- :queue.to_list(waiting) do
        GenServer.reply(from, :done)
      end

      {:stop, :normal, {:ok, acc}, {output, waiting, acc, fun}}
    else
      {:reply, :recv_pending, {output, waiting, acc, fun}}
    end
  end
```

Comment: Please don't add screen shots of code to your questions.  If a code sample helps to clarify the issue (especially if you're debugging something) include the actual code directly in the question.  Images are hard-to-impossible to read, can't be copied or reproduced, and can't be searched for later.

Comment: I have updated it with code now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Elixir, it is not so common to use `try` and most of the time you actually want to let it crash, not prevent it. It is the job of the supervision tree to handle the crash, not the crashing process to recover. [This article](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/try-catch-and-rescue.html#fail-fast--let-it-crash) should help.

I think this excerpt from [Joe Armstrong's thesis (2003)](https://github.com/bsless/resources/blob/master/armstrong_thesis_2003.pdf) is also very interesting and explains the philosophy behind Erlang's error handling and "let it crash":

> 1. Processes are the units of error encapsulation [...]
> 2. Processes do that they are supposed to do or fail as soon as possible
> 3. Failure, and the reason of failure, can be detected by remote processes
> 4. Processes share no state, but communicate by message passing

Also, I think you are confusing `catch` and `rescue` here: `catch` is mean to get a value being passed by `throw`, while `rescue` can recover from unexpected errors.

Comment: If one error happen, the same error will happen quickly after restart. Errors will happen quickly, until the supervisor shut down. How to solve it?

Comment: I suppose it depends on the error. Transient errors will probably not happen again so just restarting the process probably solves it. If you have a bug in the code causing the crash consistently, even `try/rescue` won't solve it, so the supervisor shutting down is probably the correct thing to do, while you get to check the error logs and fix the bug.

Comment: if bug exist, `try/recue` will protect the supervisor not crash, and it is easy to find bug in the log.

Comment: Preventing from crash would be against the philosophy of Erlang/Elixir, especially if you don't know what the bug is. Keeping your genserver up in a potentially corrupted state could be a bad idea and result in more problems (see the thesis above for more details). If you need to isolate your genserver from failure, maybe the operation in question should be run inside another process and your supervision tree design re-considered?

Comment: Keeping running with supposedly _wrong_ data and hence behaviour is much worse than crashing the supervisor, that’s exactly why [tag:erlang]/[tag:elixir] systems are so fault tolerant. Your supervision tree design must be aware that each and every process might crash and have a strategy to recover from. Rescuing errors makes zero sense because it literally encourages the malfunctioning code to continue run, leading to misbehaving application.

Comment: Thank you very much. These explanation are clear now and very helpful.